# How to get parameter with PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to get a certain parameter like this:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['param'];
?>
```

But if that parameter doesn't exist on a certain page, it doesn't show anything.  What do I need to change to make it check if the parameter exists?  If it exists I want it to show it, if it doesn't then I want to show text like "Not available".  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
<?php
    if(!$_GET['param']){
        echo "Not Available";
    }else{
        echo $_GET['param'];
    }
?>
```

On a side note, you could also test for `!isset($_GET['param'])`, or `$_GET['param'] != ""`

Comment: Close but not exactly.  With your code if the parameter doesn't exist, it show "Not Available" - which is correct.  But if the parameter DOES exist, I want to echo it.  Right now your code doesn't show anything when the parameter does exist.  Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: Updated, I should work on my reading skills

Answer (score 1):

Using `isset()`:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['param'])){
       echo $_GET['param'];
  }
  else {
       echo "this param doesn't exist";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Getting this error:   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/user/public_html/signup/index.php on line 308

Comment: sorry i forgot ( ,check my code now